# pgrep -f cuts commands after 4095 characters

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to use pgrep to find a running process, with an exceptionally long command, with the unique identifier at the end. However, `pgrep -af` is unable to find the process while `ps aux | grep` works just find. When finding the process using it's current user id, pgrep returns the command, but cut to exactly 4095 characters, which cuts off the unique identifier. Is there a way to use pgrep on the full command?

```
ps aux | grep gps-consumer
```

ps output:

axk7812  120227  0.6  0.6 12422920 829648 ?     Sl   Jun05  69:10 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java -cp /opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/conf/:/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/jars/*:/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/conf/yarn-conf/:/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/kafka-0.10/*:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/activation-1.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/asm-3.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/avro-1.7.6-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.6.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.10.6.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.10.6.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.6.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/aws-java-sdk-sts-1.10.6.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.1.4.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-el-1.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-io-2.4.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-net-3.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/curator-client-2.7.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/curator-framework-2.7.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/gson-2.2.4.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/guava-11.0.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/guice-3.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-ant-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-archive-logs-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-archives-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-auth-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-aws-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-azure-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-azure-datalake-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2-tests.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-datajoin-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-distcp-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-extras-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-gridmix-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2-tests.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2-tests.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-nativetask-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-nfs-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-openstack-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-rumen-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-sls-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-yarn-api-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-yarn-client-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-yarn-common-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/htrace-core4-4.0.1-incubating.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hue-plugins-3.9.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/javax.inject-1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jettison-1.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.4.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.4.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jline-2.11.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/junit-4.11.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/logredactor-1.0.3.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/microsoft-windowsazure-storage-sdk-0.6.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/okhttp-2.4.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/okio-1.4.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/paranamer-2.3.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-avro-1.5.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-cascading-1.5.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-column-1.5.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-common-1.5.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-encoding-1.5.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-format-2.1.0-cdh5.11.2-javadoc.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-format-2.1.0-cdh5.11.2-sources.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-format-2.1.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-generator-1.5.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-hadoop-1.5.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.5.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-jackson-1.5.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-pig-1.5.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-pig-bundle-1.5.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-protobuf-1.5.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-scala_2.10-1.5.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-scrooge_2.10-1.5.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-test-hadoop2-1.5.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-thrift-1.5.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/parquet-tools-1.5.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/spark-1.6.0-cdh5.11.2-yarn-shuffle.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/xz-1.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/lib/hadoop/LICENSE.txt:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/lib/hadoop/NOTICE.txt -Xmx2g -DPHDTKafkaConsumer.app.log4j=/home/axk7812/delivery-tracking-dev/realtime-tracking-mobile/conf/log4j.properties org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --master local[4] --conf spark.driver.memory=2g --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-DPHDTKafkaConsumer.app.log4j=/home/axk7812/delivery-tracking-dev/realtime-tracking-mobile/conf/log4j.properties --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-DPHDTKafkaConsumer.app.log4j=/home/axk7812/delivery-tracking-dev/realtime-tracking-mobile/conf/log4j.properties --class com.pizzahut.deliverytracking.impl.consumer.GPSDataConsumer /home/axk7812/delivery-tracking-dev/realtime-tracking-mobile/lib/gps-consumer.jar -conf /home/axk7812/delivery-tracking-dev/realtime-tracking-mobile/conf/application.conf

```
pgrep -af gps-consumer
# No output
pgrep -u axk7812 -a
```

pgrep output:
120227 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java -cp /opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/conf/:/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/jars/*:/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/conf/yarn-conf/:/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/kafka-0.10/*:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/activation-1.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/asm-3.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/avro-1.7.6-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.6.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.10.6.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.10.6.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.6.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/aws-java-sdk-sts-1.10.6.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.1.4.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-el-1.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-io-2.4.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/commons-net-3.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/curator-client-2.7.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/curator-framework-2.7.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/gson-2.2.4.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/guava-11.0.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/guice-3.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-ant-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-archive-logs-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-archives-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-auth-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-aws-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-azure-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/jars/hadoop-azure-datalake-2.6.0-cdh5.11.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-

I would expect the first pgrep to find the process just as ps does, but it is unable to find anything after 4095 characters.

Comment: A few less lines of output would have been enough to demonstrate the problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which `pgrep` you're using, but in Debian's `pgrep` from `procps-ng`, this is a [hard coded limit](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/2e7f38707a1fa5949ccf3655fa33a90c8b8a2ffc/pgrep.c#L45):

```
#define CMDSTRSIZE 4096
```

You therefore can't really get around it with this tool.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of indirecting through 3rd-party tools, if you want the accurate argv, you should be going straight to the source -- the kernel, via procfs -- yourself.

```
argv_for() {
  local arg pid=$1
  local -a args=()
  while IFS= read -r -d '' arg; do
    args+=( "$arg" )
  done <"/proc/$pid/cmdline"
  printf '%q ' "${args[@]}" && printf '\s'
}

argv_for 7819
```

That way you avoid `pgrep`'s (or `ps`'s) built-in limitations, *including* such bugs as simply using string concatenation to try to build a command line (which can be very, very dangerous to trust; if a program was run as `./myprog '$(rm -rf ~)'`, you don't want it showing up as `./myprog $(rm -rf ~)`, but that all-too-often happens in tools that were written to display data to a user, vs written to form that data into a legitimate, safely-runnable command line).